# Bootstrap 3 - Make AJAX call for a link inside table in a tab and load content inside the tab

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-tabs

My tabs definition:

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="rcg-tabs">
<li><a href="#tasks" data-toggle="tab">Tasks</a></li>
<li><a href="#canon-input" data-toggle="tab">Canonicalization</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
<div class="tab-pane active" id="tasks">
    <table title="Job Names" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover table-condensed">
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Execution&nbsp;Count</th>
            <th>Launchable</th>
            <th>Incrementable</th>
        </tr>
        <#list jobs as job>
            <tr>
                <#assign job_url><@spring.url relativeUrl="${servletPath}/jobs/${job.name}"/></#assign>
                <td><a href="${job_url}">${job.name}</a></td>
                <td><@spring.messageText code="${job.name}.description" text="No description"/></td>
                <td>${job.executionCount}</td>
                <td><#if job.launchable??>${job.launchable?string}<#else>?</#if></td>
                <td><#if job.incrementable??>${job.incrementable?string}<#else>?</#if></td>
            </tr>
        </#list>
    </table>
</div>

<div class="tab-pane" id="canon-input">
    <s:if test="hasFieldErrors()">
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <s:fielderror theme="bootstrap"/>
        </div>
    </s:if>
    <s:form action="canonicalize-logs" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post"
        theme="bootstrap" cssClass="form-horizontal form-canon" validate="true">
        <!-- 
        <s:fielderror fieldName="canonicalizationDate" theme="bootstrap"/>
         -->
        <div class="form-group input-group" id="canonicalizeDate">

            <label for="canonicalizationDate">Date</label>
            <input type="text" id="canonicalizationDate"
                name="canonicalizationDate" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy"
                class="form-control datepicker"/>
        </div>
        <!-- 
        <s:fielderror fieldName="canonicalizationHour" theme="bootstrap"/>
        -->
        <div class="form-group input-group">
            <label for="canonicalizationHour">Hour</label>
            <select class="form-control" name="canonicalizationHour" id="canonicalizationHour">
                <option value="-1">Select Hour</option>
                <s:iterator var="hour" begin="0" end="%{dayHours}">
                    <option value="<s:property/>"><s:property value="#hour"/></option>  
                </s:iterator>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Canonicalize Logs</button>
        </div>
    </s:form>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This will render the tabs as show in the screenshot below (I have removed the code for Status tab for brevity):
[image: bootstrap3-tabs]

When I click on the hyperlink initialCanonJob, I would like to make an AJAX call and then load the html content from the AJAX call back in the same tab (The Table will have to be removed).
How do I get the tab object from the link and then populate the data from the AJAX call inside the tab html?

```js
$('a').click(function (event){
event.preventDefault();
var jobUrl = "" + $(this).attr('href') + "";
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url : jobUrl,
    error: function (data) {
        console.log("Error occurred when retrieving job executions");
    },
    success: function (data) {
        //how to get the tab object and populate data?
        alert(data);
    }
});
});
```

Comment: If I'm not wrong (because I didn't read your question to the end) your current clicked tab will be `$(this)` so you can operate with it

Comment: Pavio - wouldn't $(this) be the anchor tag? Because $(this).attr('href') gives me the url of the href link.

Comment: Yes, it would be your anchor, but as an example you can do the next thing with it `var currentHref = $(this).attr('href'); alert($("."+currentHref).html());` will be your table. Please check. But don't forget remove `#` from your href

Comment: Pavio - I get Uncaught Syntax error, unrecognized expression: ./rcg-web/admin-console/jobs/initialCanonJob error where /rcg-web/admin-console/jobs/initialCanonJob is the href url

Comment: `alert(jobUrl)` should return `#tasks` or `#canon-input`, shouldn't it? Because your anchors are tabs.

Comment: Pavlo - My anchors aren't tabs. <a href="${job_url}">${job.name}</a> is my anchor and this is embedded with the <td> tag

Comment: Pavlo - I did this: var tabPane = $('#tasks'); make an AJAX call; $(tabPane).html(data) - This works. The only downside I am hard coding the id of the tab in the javascript code.

Comment: What about `alert($('.tab-pane.active').html())` this should be your selected tab. Is that something your wanted?

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion would be, you can append more data's to initialCanonJob like 
`<div id='some-1' style='color:aqua' class='someTitle' name='url'> initialCanonJob <input type='hidden' id='hidSome-1' value='URL'></div>`

You can try as both Name / Hidden. Jquery as follows.

```
$(".someTitle").click(function(e){
   var getID = $this.id.replace('some-'); // you will have 1 here
   var getURLHiddent = $("#hidSome-"+getID).val();// if hidden method follow 
   var getURL = $(this).attr('name');
   $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url : getURLHiddent, //getURL
    error: function (data) {
        console.log("Error occurred when retrieving job executions");
    },
    success: function (data) {
        //how to get the tab object and populate data?
        alert(data);
    }
});

}
```

Comment: Santhosh - How will this help me in getting hold of the tab object where I can display the ajax result?

Comment: Anand- on success you get the data you can append to the table back. Just segregate and append it to table.

Comment: Santhosh - I want to remove the table and add the result to the tab not the table. Thanks!

Comment: You can try $("#tableID").remove(); $("tabID").append(result Data as html);